# Ubuntu One stuck on "File Sync Starting" on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-one-windows

When I first installed Ubuntu One on my computer it worked fine and synced everything. But after I rebooted it refused to sync anything and is stuck on "File Sync Starting". Can anyone point out how to fix this?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me....

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was Windows 7 Professional 64bit with all user profiles and ProgramData moved to D: drive (during Windows 7 installation).

I've checked the logs at:

D:\Users\Wojtek\AppData\Local\xdg\cache\ubuntuone\log

and found this:

```
exceptions.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\ProgramData\\ubuntuone-storageprotocol\\UbuntuOne-Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem'
```

It was obvious that there is no C:\ProgramData\ubuntuone-storageprotocol on my C: drive because it was on D: :)

I've created symlink (with cmd.exe as administrator):

```
mklink /D C:\ProgramData\ubuntuone-storageprotocol D:\ProgramData\ubuntuone-storageprotocol
```

and restarted Ubuntu One - and it started to work!

Answer (score 1):

We have not started testing Ubuntu One in windows 8 (since it's not released yet ;-). Could you file a bug in the launchpad bug tracker? Maybe we can figure out what's wrong.

Here's the URL to file a bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug

Comment: Added the bug report:)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Vista HB. Checking the logs I read something similar to incorrect bytes on some windows shortcuts (.lnk files). I removed the mentioned shortcuts and restarted ubuntu one.

Problem seems to be resolved so far.
Hope this helps, I found my ubuntu one logs from the following location
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\xdg\cache\ubuntuone\log`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and checking the log at the above directory tree titled "syncdaemon-exceptions.log" I found a reference to a single .lnk file that was causing problems.  I deleted all .lnk files on both my Ubuntu 13.04 netbook (no problems) and my Windows 7 computer that was choking on the .lnk file, restarted UbuntuOne and it synced up immediately.

For me, these .lnk files are littered on my Ubuntu computer when I used MS Office in Wine.  Office seems to make an updated .lnk file every 5 or 10 minutes sometimes, appending with sequential numbering in parentheses, such as filename.docx (4).lnk.  Since I try to sync my netbook with my work computer (Windows 7) via UbuntuOne, they end up causing problems on my Windows computer.